# Edit and create HTML content using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I want to create html content that looks something like this using `node.js`.

```
<div class="outputs">
   ...
</div>
```

I have the following code:

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var Url = require("./models/Url");
var shortId = require("shortid");
var http = require("http");
var app = express();
var { JSDOM } = jsdom;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
mongoose.connect(process.env.MLAB_URI);

app.get("/urls", (req, res, next) => {
  Url.find({}, function(err, data) {
    res.json(data);
    console.log(data.length);
  });
});

app.get("/deletebase", (req, res, next) => {
  Url.deleteMany({}, function(err, data) {
    res.json(data);
  });
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));

app.get("/:shortUrl", function(req, res, next) {
  Url.findOne({ shortUrl: req.params.shortUrl }, function(err, findUrl) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (!findUrl) {
      return next({ status: 400, message: "unknown shorturl" });
    }
    res.redirect(findUrl.longUrl);
  });
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  var url = new Url(req.body);
  var hostname = req.headers.host;
  var expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
  var regex = expression;
  if (regex.test(url) === true) {
    url.shortUrl = shortId.generate();
    url.fullUrl = "https://" + hostname + "/" + url.shortUrl;
    url.save(function(err, savedUrl) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      res.redirect("https://" + hostname);
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect("https://" + hostname);
  }
});

var options = {
  runScripts: "dangerously",
  resources: "usable"
};

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("RUNNING");
});
```

I want to get length of the data and create that many div objects with `longUrl` and `shortUrl` objects in it. Also when database will be updated new div object should be created, and when I delete database information all the div elements should be deleted too, is this possible to do?

Comment: I don't fully understand the logic here, it appears your POSTing then generating a shorturl and redirecting to it, but then on the shorturl route you're redirecting to itself, I think you should write the HTML output here instead.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44882366/271433 for examples on how to output a HTML response.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a templating engine for this the two most popular ones for Node.js are [pug(formerly Jade)](https://github.com/pugjs/pug) and [hbs(Handlebars.js)](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs).

There are a lot of other template engines [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html) you could consider.

Comment: I have index.html in my project where is stored everything, and i just want to edit it with node.js and add some div objects

Comment: I personally like ejs because it is so similar to PHP. https://ejs.co/