# how can i print discord messages to express server?

Tags: node.js, express

I have been searching for a long time how I can send a discord message to my site.
then i found the express, i don't understand how to print data to site when discord message event is triggered can you help with this issue?

I just tried the following but it only works once and then it doesn't work again

```
 const {Client} = require("discord.js")
const client = new Client({intents: ["GUILDS","GUILD_MEMBERS","GUILD_MESSAGES","GUILD_PRESENCES"]})
client.login("token")
client.on("ready", () => {
console.log("oks")
})
const express = require("express")
var app = express();

client.on("message",  message => {
    app.get("/",function(qu,res){
        res.send(message.content)
       })
       })
    })
let servers = app.listen(3000,function(){
})
```

Comment: Can you add what you have and what you have tried?

Comment: i edited can you check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `messageCreate` because the `message` event is depreciated. `app.get()` should be defined outside your message event listener. I'm not sure what you mean by "print data to site", but you can add every message sent to a database or maybe a JSON file if you'd like, and send that data through express. If you want messages on your site updated in real-time look into sockets.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
const { Client } = require("discord.js")
const express = require("express")

const client = new Client({ intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES"] })
const app = express();
const messages = []

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json(messages)
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("ready!")
})

client.on("message",  message => {
    messages.push(message)
})

client.login("token")
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("listening on port 3000")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but how can I print it to an html file on my page when I enter express?

Comment: Does this link answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601424/render-raw-html-in-response-with-express